# Browserify and script loading optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

Doesn't using Browserify to load scripts like jQuery preclude the potentials benefits of using a CDN outlined here:

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

> "Potentially the greatest benefit of using the Google AJAX Libraries
>   CDN is that your users may not need to download jQuery at all. No
>   matter how well optimized your site is, if you’re hosting jQuery
>   locally then your users must download it at least once. Each of your
>   users probably already has dozens of identical copies of jQuery in
>   their browser’s cache, but those copies of jQuery are ignored when
>   they visit your site. However, when a browser sees references to
>   CDN-hosted copies of jQuery, it understands that all of those
>   references do refer to the exact same file. With all of these CDN
>   references point to exactly the same URLs, the browser can trust that
>   those files truly are identical and won’t waste time re-requesting the
>   file if it’s already cached. Thus, the browser is able to use a single
>   copy that’s cached on-disk, regardless of which site the CDN
>   references appear on."

if so, would that mean you would want to include jQuery in the `<head>` and keep it out of your Browserify bundle?

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't using Browserify to load scripts like jQuery preclude the potentials benefits of using a CDN outlined here:

Yes.

> would that mean you would want to include jQuery in the `<head>` and keep it out of your Browserify bundle?

Yessir, then you can use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) so you can still `require()` jQuery in your browserified modules.